# is there some way execute every element simply?

Tags: python, python-3.x

normal way:

```
for x in myList:
    myFunc(x)
```

you must use a variable  x

use

```
map(myFunc,myList)
```

and in fact you must use this to make above work

```
list(map(myFunc,myList))
```

that would build a list,i don't need to build a list

maybe some one would suggest me doing this

```
def func(l):
   for x in l:
        ....
```

that is another topic

is there something like this?

```
every(func,myList)
```

Comment: Your question is - how can I execute a function for each element in some list? What is wrong with using `map()`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it builds a list (most likely a list of `None`s) in memory.

Comment: The `for` loop (or a similar list comprehension) seems pretty succinct to me. Sometimes, making things as short as possible is more an obsession than a good habit. Succinctness is good for readability, but only up to a point. Natural language has lots of redundancy for a reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'normal way' is definitely the best way, although [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) does offer the *consume* recipe for whatever reason you might need it:

```
import collections
from itertools import islice

def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

This could be used like:

```
consume(imap(func, my_list), None) # On python 3 use map
```

This function performs the fastest as it avoids python for loop overhead by using functions which run on the C side.

Comment: This is nice, but its like using a canon to punch holes in paper - I would like to know what is the OP's issue with using map().

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I replied to your comment above :)

Comment: Instead of the generator expression, you can use `itertools.imap` (since you're already using itertools)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I wasn't sure whether to do that or not due to Python 3 differences but I'll provide the two alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no 'foreach' shortcut in the standard library, but such a thing is very easy to implement:

```
def every(fun, iterable):
    for i in iterable:
        fun(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `myList` to be modified to contain `myFunc(x)` for all x in `myList` then you could try a list comprehension which also requires a variable, but doesn't let the variable leak out of the scope of the comprehension:

```
myList = [myFunc(x) for x in myList]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: *"that would build a list,i don't need to build a list"*